# Separate date and time in the input type

Tags: reactjs, datetimepicker

I am using  in the React. This defines a date picker. This date picker is working in my components. Now my problem is how to separate time and date into two different input types?

For example `datetime-local` show the date picker below:

[image: datetime]

But now I want to separate the date and time into 2 input types.

For example, I want to show the only date in the input type like below:

[image: date]

For example, I want to show the only time in the input type like below:

[image: time]

This one is my existing coding show the datetime picker in the react:

```html
<Form.Control
type="datetime-local"
name="appointmentDate"
value={selectedDate}
min={newDateValue}
onChange={(e) => handleDateChange(e.target.value)}
format={SAASDateTimeFormat}
/>
```

**Reasons:**

Why do I want to use the `datetime-local` input type to separate time and date? Because I want to standardize to the same UI for all Date & Time on the webpage, some pages use `dateime-local` input type to show the date picker with time, some pages only use `time` input type, some pages only use `date` input. So I want to try to use `datetime-local` type to separate date and time.

May I know if is it possible to separate date and time in the `datetime-local` type? Hope someone can guide me on how to solve these problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define the date and time in your input type.

For example:

Time-

type="time"

Date-

type="date"